# Why does ABAP round a number down to the nearest integer when using the REDUCE operator?

Tags: abap

In the code below, `lv_sum_openamount` should be 3.45 but the program rounds the number as 3.

I want `lv_sum_openamount` as 3.

How can I do that ?

```
DATA(lv_sum_openamount) = REDUCE dmbtr_cs( INIT sum = 0 FOR wa_amnt IN <fs_comp> NEXT sum += wa_amnt-open_amount.

LOOP AT <fs_comp> ASSIGNING <fs_comp_alv>.
  TRY.
    <fs_comp_alv>-pull_amount = ( <fs_pack>-reamount / lv_sum_openamount ) * <fs_comp_alv>-open_amount.
  CATCH cx_sy_zerodivide.
    <fs_comp_alv>-pull_amount = 0.
  ENDTRY.
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Because you use an implicit type recognition by declaring your variable inline. This implicit type has no decimal places. It is P(7) I guess. You need to declare the variable explicitely with the type you want.

Comment: @Jagger You are talking the implicit declaration of the auxiliary variable `sum`. Using an integer will implicitly declare the variable as integer, not `P(7)`. Instead of `sum = 0`, a workaround is to use `sum TYPE dmbtr_cs` (and the variable has the initial value `0`).

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is the part `INIT sum = 0`.

`0` is an integer, so the type for `sum` gets automatically derived as an integer. That means that the `REDUCE`-loop then uses integer arithmetic, so its output is rounded down.

Try `INIT sum = CONV dmbtr_cs( 0 )` instead. This will convert the literal of `0` to the type you need and in turn force `sum` to also get that type.